# CSS variable 2 Column Layout

Tags: css, html

So I've looked up stuff all over the internet and I can't find the answer I'm looking for.

I'm just trying to make a 2 column layout for a part in my page with each column being the same width, 50% of the container.

Now for some reason when I set both divs to 50% and float:left, the second div wraps underneath. The closest thing I can get is floating the second div right and making width 49% but I'd like it to be 50% because I want to have them touching.

Here is a demonstration:

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/VbWbc/)

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define **border** to your DIV's. Which add width to it for example 5`0% + 2px` . So, use **box-sizing: border-box;**

Write like this:

```
div#textBooks,
div#info{
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

check this http://jsfiddle.net/VbWbc/4/

Note: it's work's till IE8 & above.

For all browsers

Check  this http://jsfiddle.net/VbWbc/5/
write like this:

```
div#info{
    width:50%;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color:red;
    float:left;
}

div#textBooks{
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color:green;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: That helped a lot thanks, but is there a way to make it so the inner divs are as tall as the container? because if one is taller than the other and i have background colors it looks bad. I'd like them to stay the same height

Answer (score 0):

The border widths are set to 1px, so they will be adding an additional 2px to each of the two `div`s. Therefore, your content is 4px too wide to fit into that `div`.

What you need to do is encase the content of your `div`s within another `div`, and apply the border to the inner `div`. Like seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Pbfm/).

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS3 `box-sizing: border-box;`

Add this-

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-o-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing:border-box;
```

in `#inf`o and `#textBooks`

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/VbWbc/3/)

Comment: This would not work in IE7 and lower. See [compatibility chart](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing).

Comment: @Eric that's right! The example you have posted works in all browsers but kills semantic values - too many divs :)

Comment: Sometimes values have to be sacrificed for compatibility... (Just ask any Android programmer.)

Comment: @Eric OP use **display:table** property in his code. Which support till IE8 & above.